# count elements after DOM change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

so currently using ajax with JQuery .post to return a form populate with some values. What I am trying to do is basically identify if the content contains checkboxes using:

```
var count = $('#form').find('checkbox').length;
alert(count);
```

however even when it does contain checkboxes the output is 0. So do I have the syntax wrong or is it something to do with the fact the checkboxes weren't in the original DOM?

many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no tag `checkbox`, you will need to use the [`:checkbox` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector

```
$('#form').find(':checkbox').length;
```

or the more verbose

```
$('#form').find('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
```

Comment: always something so stupid at this time of night. many thanks :)